# Linear map preserving area?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, curves

In Sean Dineen's book for multivariate calculus and geometry, there is an exercise which states:

> If $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear mapping such that $$\|T(x)\|= \|x \| \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n,$$ then $T$ preserves the inner product, angle, area as well as length of curve. (Page $50,$ last problem of exercise $5$).

I have shown that $T$ preserves the inner product and angle, however I do not understand what is meant by area in this case and neither I am understanding how to show that the length isn't changing. Any help would be appreciated. I only know curves and haven't read what surfaces are yet, if that is relevant..

Comment: Preserving area means if you have a body $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ then the area of $B$ and the area of the image of $B$ under the map $T$ (we commonly write $T(B)$ to denote this) are the same.

Comment: What is meant by area of a subset of Rⁿ?

Comment: $B$ must be a 2-dimensional body in a sense that there is some plane $P \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, such that $B \subset P$. Then, in that plane, area is defined as usual. Consider, for example, the square with vertices $(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (1,1,0), (0,1,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, its area is well-defined...

Comment: Isometries in $\Bbb R^n$ are either translation, rotation or reflection. In all of these transformations the area of the rigid body remains unaltered.

Comment: What can you say about $\det T$?

Comment: You can read up one-parameter Hausdorff measures. There's a corresponding measure theoretic change of variable formula and even in that case $\mu_\alpha (S) = \mu_\alpha ( T(S))$ for any $S$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the matrix associated to $T$, that is, $T(x)=Ax$.

From the standard result in multi-variable differentiation, $dT_x(v)=Av$. (In other words, the differentiation matrix $\frac{\partial T^i}{\partial x_j}$ is exactly $A$.)

What you have proved is $|Av|=|v|$ and $Ax\cdot Ay=x\cdot y$.

Regarding to the length part, let $\gamma(t)$ be a path in $\mathbb{R}^n$. What we want to show is that
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \left|\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right|dt
=
\int_a^b \left|\frac{d(T\circ\gamma)}{dt}\right|dt,
\end{align*}
which is clear since
\begin{align*}
\frac{d(T\circ\gamma)}{dt}=dT\left(\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)
=A\left(\frac{d\gamma}{dt}\right)
\end{align*}
and $|A(\gamma^{\prime})|=|\gamma^{\prime}|$.

For the area part (I guess it means volume here. If it means the area of the hypersurface, I think it would be more difficult.), we want to show that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} 1 dx = \int_{T(\Omega)} 1 dy,
\end{align*}
where $dx$ denotes $dx_1dx_2...dx_n$ and $dy$ denotes the same volume element.
By change of variable (with $y=T(x)$, injectivity of $T$ is left to you), we have
\begin{align*}
\int_{T(\Omega)}1dy&=
\int_{\Omega} \left|\det{
\left(\frac{\partial T^i}{\partial x_j}\right)}
\right| dx\\
&=\int_{\Omega} |\det{A}|dx.
\end{align*}
If we can show that $|\det{A}|=1$, then we are done.

Observe that you have already shown that $Ax \cdot Ay=x\cdot y$, which means $(A^TAx) \cdot y=x\cdot y$ for every $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Hope that you could derive the desired result from here.

Intuitively (or geometrically), preserving length and preserving angle imply preserving the volume element.